# Maximum open cursors exceeded exception in JPA (Using createNativeQuery to delete records)

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jpa

I am getting Error (Occurrence of ORA-01000 is more compared to other )-

1. ORA-01000: Maximum number of open cursors exceeded
2. ORA-00604: Error at recursive SQL level 1
3. [ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - No more data to read from socket

I will try to explain the code scenario that I am running.

1. Service Call to DAO layer to delete records where I pass primary
   keys to find and delete from table.

   ```
   @Transactional(value = "txManagerResult")
   public void deleteCalculatedLkmsEntities(final List<Long> chkdLkmsIds) {
       this.daoResult. deleteCalculatedLkmsEntitiesEnhanced(chkdLkmsIds);
   }
   ```
2. DAO method to delete records from 4 tables (having Parent and Child
   relationship on data but this relation is not maintained on Tables
   (i.e. there is no foreign key relationship).

   ```
   private void deleteCalculatedLkmsEntitiesEnhanced(final List<Long> chkdLkmsIds) {

        // Order of the delete is must be maintained as below 

        // this will delete  around 100000 rows for 1000 primary key of parent table
        this.deleteEntitiesByPrimaryKeyList("delete from Child_Table_4 where CHKD_PRODUCT_OFFERING_ID in ( "
                      + " select ID from Child_Table_2 where CHKD_LKMS_ID in ( "
                      + "select ID from Parent_Table_1 where id in (:pid) "
                      + ") )"
                      , "pid",
                      chkdLkmsIds);

   // this will delete  around 100000 rows for 1000 primary key of parent table
        this.deleteEntitiesByPrimaryKeyList("delete from Child_Table_3 where CHKD_PRODUCT_OFFERING_ID in ( "
                      + " select ID from Child_Table_2 where CHKD_LKMS_ID in ( "
                      + "select ID from Parent_Table_1 where id in (:pid) "
                      + ") )"
                      , "pid",
                      chkdLkmsIds);

   // this will delete  around 300000 rows for 1000 primary key of parent table
        this.deleteEntitiesByPrimaryKeyList("delete from Child_Table_2 where CHKD_LKMS_ID in ( "
                      + "select ID from Parent_Table_1 where id in (:pid) )"
                      , "pid",
                      chkdLkmsIds);

        // this will delete around 1000 rows
        this.deleteEntitiesByPrimaryKeyList("delete from Parent_Table_1 where ID in (:pid)"
                      , "pid",
                      chkdLkmsIds);

   } 
   private void deleteEntitiesByPrimaryKeyListFromDB(final String query, final String parameter,
               final List<Long> idsToDelete) {
        this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(query)
        .setParameter(parameter, idsToDelete).executeUpdate();
      }
   ```

The service method is called by 4 parallel threads which are managed by ForkJoinPool.

Error does not appear as soon as application start but it starts appearing after 10+ Hours of execution of the code. Above methods keep running (deleting records) by threads in cyclic manner. This process runs to complete 9 Million records execution.

Please help.

Comment: Can you also provide your *calls*

Comment: Does anything ever commit the work being done - it doesn't look like it from what you've show, unless autocommit is on? And is `entityManager.createNativeQuery()` creating a new connection each time and nothing ever closes them?

Comment: @AlexPoole Commit part is taken care by the annotation Transactional on service level method. I too suspect something is open and not getting closed by entityManager.createNativeQuery() but I am not able to find that as this is the utility provided by JPA.

Comment: @Hearen :  Call is made to the service method from Thread ( extends RecursiveAction) and those threads are managed by ForkJoinPool.

Comment: Do the *4 parallel threads* reuse the same database connection? I thing this could be the problem, JDBC is AFAIK not multi threading proof.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all the comments.. it could happen due to a lot of parallel calls. Assuming that em.createNativeQuery() is handling DB resource lifecycle properly. If you are using oracle DB, there is a restriction on maximum open cursors. You can increase the max number of open cursors at database level to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I think increasing max number of open cursor could be a workaround but difficulties lies in finding out that how many allowed open cursors needs to increased. And this does not guarantee that problem is resolved.

Comment: agree ..the idea here is that if resources are reaching it's capacity we need to allocate more. You may need to do load testing of your application using jmeter or a similar tool and come up with benchmarking to determine ideal number of open cursors to be increased. But this should be done only after we are sure that we don't have any issues with application code e.g. connection leak or resource leak in this case.